# What branch of Algebra has the most category theory in it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, category-theory

I like both category theory and algebra so I am wondering in your opinion what subject maximizes their intersection.

Comment: What sort of algebra do you like. And which parts of category theory? There are several areas especially of representation theory where category theory shows up a lot (in fact, there is a well-developed representation theory for at least certain classes of $2$-categories). Some terms that might be worth looking up to get started are algebraic categorification and $2$-representation theory (or higher representation theory).

Comment: You should rather maximize the intersection with your preferred topic in mathematics. In general, categories are part of *Homological algebra*, *Representation Theory*, *Theoretical Physics* (Braided monoidal category etc.), and many more.

Answer (score 3):

*Algebra* is a broad term, so it is a bit difficult to answer that question. But let me try to connect some sub-subjects of **category theory** with the algebraic domain they describe (or even sometimes were created for).

---

**Abelian categories.** They are the realm in which most of *homological algebra* and *topological algebra* takes place.

**Grothendieck toposes.** Those are the categories of sheaves appearing in *algebraic geometry* which, in its current form, heavily relies on category theory.

**Lawvere theories.** They are the categorical point of view on *universal algebra*. Going from there to full *model theory* will take you to **elementary toposes**.

**Monoidal categories.** They appears a lot in *theoretical quantum physics*, because it is a sort of generalized *linear algebra*. They support a very handy "visual language" (called string diagram) that mathematician-physicist are fan of because it takes the *brac-cket* notation to the next level. Keywords here are *Hopf algebras*, *Froebenius algebras*, etc.

**$\infty$-categories.** Those are categories with higher morphisms, meaning that you don't just have objects and morphisms between those, but also morphisms between morphisms, and morphisms between those, and morphisms between those ... all the way to the top ! This is where *homotopical algebra* happens. Category-keywords here are **model categories**, **simplicial categories**, etc.

**Categories.** Last but not least, categories themselves can be studied as algebras of a (essentially) algebraic theory ! Going further in that direction will eventually lead you to **enriched category theory**.

---

Of course, this list is very far from exhaustive and is more an invitation for you to research a little those fields and see if they please you.